# How do you auto kill a vb.net Windows Form Program after 2 hours as passed?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer

I'm in the middle of wrapping up a vb app I made for the company I work in, and for security purposes, they would like it if the program kept track of how long they have the program open and if that time exceeds 2 hours, they want the program to display a simple MsgBox that says "You have exceed the operational limit" or something of the like and then end the program.

I did some researching and I think System.Threading.Timer is what I need, but I'm curious if that would be intrusive to the user while they are working. The program I made is made up of various Windows Forms where the user can do a variety of tasks, and from what I saw about .Timer online is that you need to call back to it constantly, but the user might be on a different form at the time and I wouldn't want it to give control away from the user as well while they work just to check the time.

I already have a public class for Global Variables, is it possible to just keep a non-intrusive way of keeping time there no matter what form they are in and also know to kill the entire program when time is up?

Comment: Short answer a timer that checks elapsed time.  That being said, the message you display should not be a messagebox, as it will block until the user click a button.  The timer interval just set to a minute.  The logic with other forms, is a coding logic isssue, but if you need help, post your code.

Comment: PLz share the code which you have tried so far..

Comment: @Trey A MessageBox won't block a timer.

Comment: Sorry no, I meant it will block his shutting down(unless he threaded it) So if he throws up a messagebox, the app is waiting for a response, thus if they do not respond, no shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

You have several questions stacked up in this one, so I'll focus what appears to be your main one, timer.  To quickly summarize your question about it being possible to keep time in a non-intrusive way with multiple forms, yes it is, but you'll need to post another question relating to that specifically.

I agree with [Trey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2929848/trey), use a timer.  You didn't mention if this is a WinForms or WPF application, but just know that you will have a choice of timers depending on which type.

For console and WinForms you can use the System.Threading.Timer, but keep in mind that it is Asynchronous, so you will need to switch to the UI thread before displaying the MessageBox or popup Form.

In WPF you can use the System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer that provides the same functionality as the System.Threading.Timer, but ticks on the UI thread.

Since your specification is to notify the user that their time has been exceeded and end the program, I wouldn't be bothered about anything being too intrusive.  However, timers are not intrusive nor are they even noticed by the user, unless some intrusive code is run when the timer ticks.

Here is an example using the System.Threading.Timer (console or WinForms, can be used in WPF, but I would prefer DispatcherTimer):

```
Private _TimeExceededTimer As Timer

Public Sub StartTimeExceededTimer(ByVal duration TimeSpan)
    _TimeExceededTimer = New Timer(duration.TotalMilliseconds)
    AddHandler _TimeExceededTimer, AddressOf _TimeExceededTimer_Elapsed
    _TimeExceededTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub _TimeExceededTimer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    _TimeExceededTimer.Stop()
    RemoveHandler _TimeExceededTimer, AddressOf _TimeExceededTimer_Elapsed
    _TimeExceededTimer.Dispose()
    _TimeExceededTimer = Nothing
    NotifyUserThatTimeIsUp()
End Sub

Private Sub NotifyUserThatTimeIsUp()
    'At this point display a MessageBox
    'or another Form used as a popup to
    'inform the user that their time is up.
    'Keep in mind that we are NOT on the UI thread, so you will want to switch over to it.
    MessageBox.Show("Time's up!")

    'Close the application
    My.Application.Shutdown()
    'Or Application.Current.Shutdown()
End Sub
```

I hope this points you in the right direction.  Break your post up into it's various parts and we'll be able to answer the rest of your questions.